# How to generate app translations with advanced locale definition and multiple variants Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I'm trying to translate an app in differents languages but facing a problem for languages inside `fromSubtags` (ukranian & russian)
I've looked in the doc [internationalization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) so I can't declare them as `const Locale("ru", "RU")` & `const Locale("ru", "UA")`

I have to use `Locale.fromSubtags()`

It can exists only one **app_ru.arb** so how can I add ukranian in this json file an use it depending of the phone language?

**L10n**

```
class L10n {
  static final all = [
    const Locale("bg"),
    const Locale("fi", "FI"),
    const Locale("hu", "HU"),
    const Locale("ja", "JP"),
    const Locale("pl", "PL"),
    const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: "ru"),
    const Locale.fromSubtags(
        languageCode: "ru",
        countryCode: "RU"
    ),
    const Locale.fromSubtags(
        languageCode: "ru",
        countryCode: "UA"
    ),
  ];
}
```

**app_ru.arb**

```
{
    "language": "ru-RU",
    "currentTrends": "Современные тенденции",
    "currentlyAtTheCinema": "В настоящее время в кинотеатрах",
    "availableSoon": "Скоро будет",
    "animations": "Анимации",
    "adventure": "Приключение",
    "videoNotAvailable": "Видео недоступно",
    "types": "Категории:",
    "recommendedTo": "Рекомендовано",
    "play": "Чтение",
    "downloadVideo": "Скачать видео",
    "synopsisNotAvailable": "Синопсис недоступен",
    "casting": "Актеры",
    "gallery": "Галерея"
}
```

**Ukranian to add**

```
"language": "ru-UA",
"currentTrends": "Поточні тенденції",
"currentlyAtTheCinema": "Наразі в прокаті",
"availableSoon": "Доступно найближчим часом",
"animations": "Анімації",
"adventure": "Пригодницька",
"videoNotAvailable": "Відео недоступне",
"types": "Категорії:",
"recommendedTo": "Рекомендовано на",
"play": "Читання",
"downloadVideo": "Завантажити відео",
"synopsisNotAvailable": "Синопсис недоступне",
"casting": "Актори",
"gallery": "Галерея"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ukrainian locale is 'uk-UA' or just 'uk'.

Comment: @Dmytro Popov, thanks for the answer. I've found the problem, in phone settings > languages there is Russian (ukrainian)  & Ukrainian (ukrainian) with the second one it works using an `app_uk.arb`

Comment: Yes, if the language is set to Russian (Ukraine) it is still considered to be Russian. You can now answer your question and mark the answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

Settings > Languages, there's is two "kinds" of ukrainian. 
Russian (Ukrainian) `Русский (Украина)` & Ukrainian (Ukrainian) `Українська (Україна)` select the second one.

And it will works using `app_uk.arb`